# WooCommerce, after moving reviews tab to under product description. If pagination link is clicked description is hidden

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I used an unset $tab['reviews'] and added action to show reviews after product summary. It works great except for when people click on page 2 or 3 for comments. The pagination works, but then because of how reviews works, it hides the description until I click the tab for description.

Any ideas? Where does it tell that the description tab has to be hidden when reviews are paginated?

Answer (score 0):

The active tab is set in woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/single-product.js. Starting at line 11 this file looks for the words "comments" "reviews" or "tab-reviews" in the page url, and if found, it uses jQuery to click on the review tab. Since there is no review tab anymore, nothing gets clicked.

To solve this issue I overrode WooCommerce's single-product.js file by enqueue-ing a new js file under/after WC's single-product-min.js in the footer. I just copied the whole file into my theme and replaced "li.reviews_tab a" with "li.description_tab a" on lines 19 and 21. Not the most eloquent solution, but it worked for me.